# NOT expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE true instead

Tags: netlogo

I have written NetLogo code to make turtles change their decision process each run. But I got the message: NOT expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE true instead

I am new to NetLogo, Can anyone please point out where is the mistake in my code? Really appreaciated!

```
to setup
  clear-all
   create-turtles N [
        set decided-bmi? false
        set decided-achieve? false   
  ]


end

to go

  ask turtles 
   [if (not decided-bmi? )
  
  
    [
      decide-bm-intention
   
      set decided-bmi? true
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your problem is. I ran the code you provided (Had to add the turtle-own variables and a procedure for `decide-bmi-intention` for the code to work). Everything works without any errors.

```
turtles-own [decided-bmi? decided-achieve?]

to setup
  clear-all
   create-turtles 5 [
        set decided-bmi? false
        set decided-achieve? false   
  ]
  
end

to go

  ask turtles 
   [if (not decided-bmi? )
  
  
    [
      decide-bm-intention
   
      set decided-bmi? true
    ]
  ]
  
end

to decide-bm-intention
  
  print "a"
  
end
```

Did you copypaste the error or did you write it? Since your error doesn't really make sense and it is quite easy to get the opposite error `NOT expected input to be a TRUE/FALSE but got the number 0 instead.` That error would occur if you had any turtle for which you did not do `set decided-bmi? false` since the default value for turtles-own variables is 0.